# Integrate does not accept my integrand expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I want to calculate the symbolic integral, but I could not obtain the final results from Mathematica.

```
$Assumptions = R > 0 && f > 0 && m ∈ Integers;
a1[a_] := Log[R Sqrt[2 (1 - Cos[a])]];
b[a_] := R (1 - Cos[a]);
c[a_] := R Sin[a];
d2[a_] := 2 R R (1 - Cos[a]);
d4[a_] := d2[a]^2;
Ebb[a_] := -a1[a] + b[a]^2/d2[a];
Ebc[a_] := b[a] c[a]/d2[a];
Ecc[a_] := -a1[a] + c[a]^2/d2[a];
fb[a_] := f Cos[m a];
fc[a_] := f Sin[m a];
```

when I calcualted wb ingetral as follows:

```
wb = Integrate[Ebb[a] fb[a] + Ebc[a] fc[a], {a, 0, 2  π}]
```

I found the result was not calculated -- I got the output:

[image: output]

Where did I make a mistake?

Could you tell me how to do one bit more complicated integral by your method, please? I used the same method as you provided, but failed this time. Here I just introduced another angle u besides the angle a, and made fb and fc a little more complicated. But I guess that these minor changes should not affect your method to be applied.

```
a1[a_, u_] := Log[R Sqrt[2 (1 - Cos[u - a])]];
b[a_, u_] := R (1 - Cos[u - a]);
c[a_, u_] := R Sin[u - a];
d2[a_, u_] := 2 R R (1 - Cos[u - a]);
d4[a_, u_] := d2[a, u]^2;
Ebb[a_, u_] := -a1[a, u] + b[a, u]^2/d2[a, u];
Ebc[a_, u_] := b[a, u] c[a, u]/d2[a, u];
Ecc[a_, u_] := -a1[a, u] + c[a, u]^2/d2[a, u];
fb[a_] := Refb Cos[m a] - Infb Sin[m a];
fc[a_] := Refc Cos[m a] - Infc Sin[m a];


$Assumptions = True;
wb = Integrate[Ebb[a, u] fb[a] + Ebc[a, u] fc[a], {a, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
Assumptions -> R > 0 && Refb > 0 && Infb > 0 && Refc > 0 && Infc > 0 && m \[Element] Integers && {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

> ```
> 1/2 (-((2 Infb Sin[m \[Pi]]^2)/m) + (Refb Sin[2 m \[Pi]])/m + (1/(m^2))Infb (-Hypergeometric2F1[1, -m, 1 - m, E^(-I u)] + 
>   Hypergeometric2F1[1, m, 1 + m, E^(-I u)] - 
>   Cos[2 m \[Pi]] Hypergeometric2F1[1, m, 1 + m, 
>     Cos[u] - I Sin[u]] + 2 m Log[R] - 2 m Cos[2 m \[Pi]] Log[R] + 
>   m Log[2 - 2 Cos[u]] - m Cos[2 m \[Pi]] Log[2 - 2 Cos[u]] + 
>   Hypergeometric2F1[1, -m, 1 - m, 
>     Cos[u] - I Sin[u]] (Cos[2 m \[Pi]] - I Sin[2 m \[Pi]]) + 
>   I Sin[2 m \[Pi]] - 
>   I Hypergeometric2F1[1, m, 1 + m, Cos[u] - I Sin[u]] Sin[
>     2 m \[Pi]]) + (1/(m^2)) I Refb (1 - Cos[2 m \[Pi]] - 
>   Hypergeometric2F1[1, -m, 1 - m, E^(-I u)] - 
>   Hypergeometric2F1[1, m, 1 + m, E^(-I u)] + 
>   Cos[2 m \[Pi]] Hypergeometric2F1[1, m, 1 + m, 
>     Cos[u] - I Sin[u]] + 
>   Hypergeometric2F1[1, -m, 1 - m, 
>     Cos[u] - I Sin[u]] (Cos[2 m \[Pi]] - I Sin[2 m \[Pi]]) + 
>   I Hypergeometric2F1[1, m, 1 + m, Cos[u] - I Sin[u]] Sin[
>     2 m \[Pi]] + 2 I m Log[R] Sin[2 m \[Pi]] + 
>   I m Log[2 - 2 Cos[u]] Sin[2 m \[Pi]]) - (Refb (m Cos[u] Sin[2 m \[Pi]] - 2 Sin[m \[Pi]]^2 Sin[u]))/(-1 + 
> m^2) + (Infb (2 m Cos[u] Sin[m \[Pi]]^2 + 
>   Sin[2 m \[Pi]] Sin[u]))/(-1 + m^2) + (1/(-1 + m^2)) 2 Sin[m \[Pi]] (Sin[m \[Pi]] (Refc Cos[u] - Infc m Sin[u]) + 
>   Cos[m \[Pi]] (Infc Cos[u] + m Refc Sin[u])))
> ```

The help of `Limit` failed this time:

```
Limit[wb, m -> #] & /@ Range[-2, 2]
```

The final result is too long, so I do not copy it here. I am not sure where I made a mistake.

Comment: v8.0.4 evaluates to `0`.

Comment: No. I wonder there is a bug in Mathematica. If I chose m=2, I can obtain f\Pi/2. But I could not get the final result by symbolic calculation.

Comment: You're right. Seems to be a bug at least to v8.0.4. BTW, if I introduce the assumptions with `Assumption` option of `Integrate`, the calculation seems to last forever. Maybe you can report it to Wolfram company?

Comment: It is strange. My friend used maple to obtain the final result f\Pi/m for the generalization of m. And if I did not give the assumptions, and then integrate the same integrand from 0 to 2Pi and from -Pi to Pi give us two different results.

Comment: The integration with `Assumptions` option inside `Integrate` just finished and it gave back the input 囧. A friend of mine has also tried Maple 18 but it gave back the input (Maybe it's because he isn't good at Maple? ). Also, when `m = 0`, the result isn't actually `f Pi/m` but `f Pi (1 - 2 Log[R])`. As to the integration without assumptions, the results of that from `0` to `2 Pi` and from `-Pi` to `Pi` seem to be the same when `Element[m, Integers]`, and though a direct substitution of `m` won't work, we can get a simplified result for a specific `m` with `Limit`.

Comment: I have no idea. My Mathematica 9 also gives back the input as I showed above. Yes, your friend's result from Maple is correct. My friend used maple and assume m as nonzero integer. Then he obtained a very nice result f\Pi/m. But m=0 needs to be deal with separately.

Comment: Seems that I've made some kind of mistake Saturday. Today I retried `Assumptions` option inside Integrate and it gives the correct result. See the answer for details.

Comment: For your new piece of code, v8.0.4 gives `{0, -(1/2) π ((Infc + Refb) Cos[u] + (Infb - Refc) Sin[u]), 
 DirectedInfinity[-I Sign[Infb]], 
 1/2 π ((Infc - Refb) Cos[u] + (Infb + Refc) Sin[u]), 0}`.

Comment: How did you obtain it?

Comment: Nothing special, I just ran your code. Seems that my result of `Integrate` is different from yours. Have you tried the code with a fresh kernel?

Comment: Assumptions -> R > 0 && Refb > 0 && Infb > 0 && Refc > 0 && Infc > 0 && m \[Element] Integers && {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]  . Is it correctly used by me? Specially on the angle u assumption part.

Comment: Yes, I shut down Mathematica 9, and then restart it, but I still could not obtain your result.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice this, the syntax is incorrect, it should be `0 < u < 2 Pi`, and after adding this, the integration becomes slower and I don't want to wait, but deleting the assumption for `u` yields the same result as the `{u, 0, 2Pi}` case.

Comment: If remove 0 < u < 2 Pi, Mathematica 6.0 could not give any result. It could give (\[ImaginaryI] \[Pi] (Infb Cos[m u] + Refb Sin[m u]))/m only with the condition 0 < u < 2 Pi, but 6.0 version could not give the integral $Assumptions = True;
wc = Integrate[Ebc[a, u] fb[a] + Ecc[a, u] fc[a], {a, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  Assumptions -> 
   R > 0 && Refb > 0 && Infb > 0 && Refc > 0 && Infc > 0 && 
    m \[Element] Integers && 0 < u < 2 \[Pi]]. It just gave back the integral. Mathematica 9 completely did not work for any integral.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug. Maybe you can report it to Wolfram company.

Here's just some observations with v8.0.4.

If the assumptions are introduced by `$Assumptions`, the result is apparently incorrect:

```
$Assumptions = R > 0 && f > 0 && m ∈ Integers;
Integrate[Ebb[a] fb[a] + Ebc[a] fc[a], {a, 0, 2 π}]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

but things will be different if we turn to `Assumptions` inside `Integrate`:

```
$Assumptions = True;
wb = Integrate[Ebb[a] fb[a] + Ebc[a] fc[a], {a, 0, 2 π}, 
  Assumptions -> R > 0 && f > 0 && m ∈ Integers]
```

> ```
> 1/4 f (-(1/(m^2)) I E^(-2 I m π) (-1 + E^(2 I m π)) (-1 + E^(2 I m π) + 
>    2 EulerGamma m + 2 E^(2 I m π) EulerGamma m + I m π + 
>    I E^(2 I m π) m π - 2 m Log[R] - 2 E^(2 I m π) m Log[R] + 2 m PolyGamma[0, -m] + 
>    2 E^(2 I m π) m PolyGamma[0, m]) + (2 Sin[2 m π])/m - (2 Sin[2 m π])/(1 + m))
> ```

A direct substitution of `m` to this `wb` will lead to errors:

```
wb /. List /@ Thread[m -> Range[-2, 2]]
```

> *Warnings…*
>
> ```
> {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate}
> ```

But we can get correct result with the help of `Limit`:

```
Limit[wb, m -> #] & /@ Range[-2, 2]
```

> ```
> {(f π)/2, 0, f π (1 - 2 Log[R]), f π, (f π)/2}
> ```

Though the form looks different, the integrals taken by $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $[0,2\pi]$ are in fact the same:

```
wb2 = Integrate[Ebb[a] fb[a] + Ebc[a] fc[a], {a, 0, 2 π}, 
  Assumptions -> R > 0 && f > 0 && m ∈ Integers];

Limit[ans, m -> #] & /@ Range[-4, 4] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> {(f π)/4, (f π)/3, (f π)/2, 0, f π (1 - 2 Log[R]), f π, (f π)/2, (f π)/3, (f π)/4}
> ```

Finally, the real problem may lie in `Simplify`:

```
Simplify[wb, m ∈ Integers]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Notice that it probably cannot be called a bug of `Simplify` because this behavior seems to be already covered by the **Possible Issues** of the documents of [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html) and [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullSimplify.html).

So, just a guess, `Integrate` have internally use `Simplify` to simplify the final result and this lead to the incorrect result of the first sample. (`$Assumptions` is also used by `Simplify`.) *I think I used to see a post that comes to the similar conclusion in this site, but I can't find it right now.*

BTW, if you want to get a simplified but incomplete result, you can try:

```
Simplify[FunctionExpand@wb, m ∈ Integers]
```

> ```
> (f π)/m
> ```

Some of the solutions are lost, it's not surprising because it's mentioned in the **Possible Issues** of the document of [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FunctionExpand.html) that some transformations used by `FunctionExpand` are only generically valid.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your comments are very helpful. But why are the integrals taken by [0,2 π] and [-π, π] different?

Comment: @HaoWu Check my edit. BTW, my friend still can't get `f Pi/m` with his Maple 18 even with the assumption `m!=0`, can you provide the code?

Comment: I am not a maple user. I will ask my friend how he did it. Oh, I found my result from Mathematica 9 is a bit different from yours by the same way. My result is (1/(4 m^2))E^(-2 I m \[Pi]) (-1 + E^(2 I m \[Pi])) f (I + m \[Pi] - 
   2 I m HarmonicNumber[-1 - m] + 2 I m Log[R] + 
   E^(2 I m \[Pi]) (-I + m \[Pi] - 
      2 I m (EulerGamma - Log[R] + PolyGamma[0, m])))  . After using Limit[wb, m -> #] & /@ Range[-2, 2], it gives {(f \[Pi])/2, f \[Pi], -2 f \[Pi] Log[R], f \[Pi], (f \[Pi])/2}

Comment: Sorry, I do not know why, but when I rerun Mathematica 9, it gives the same result as yours this time.